# Can a perpendicular slope be calculated for a slope expressed as a decimal?

Tags: geometry

If I am given the slope of a line, expressed as a decimal, is it at all possible to find the perpendicular slope, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your slope is $m_1$ the slope $m_2$ of the perpendicular satisfies $m_1m_2=-1$

Note that if $y=mx+c$, $m=\tan\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the line and the $x$=axis.

$\tan(a-b)=\cfrac {\tan a - \tan b}{1+\tan a \tan b}=\cfrac {m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$ and we want $a-b=90^{\circ}$